# Why does the program loop the same output if the user inputs a number higher then 10?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, placeholder

I was assigned a program in C to get a users input for how much additional water will be added to a fish tank, and after 24 hours the fish will be "BBQ'd". The problem that I'm having is if i input a higher number then 10 in scanf. The loop repeats and gives the same output forever. Am i using the correct place holder for scanf?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    //Declares variables
    double fishTank = 500;
    int hours = 0;
    int addWater;
    //asks user for input.
    printf("Please enter additional water to be added per hour:");
    scanf("%d", &addWater);

    //while fishtank is greater then or equal to 100 it will run this loop
    while (fishTank >= 100) {
        fishTank = fishTank - (fishTank * .1) + addWater;
        printf("The tank still has %f gallons remaining\n", fishTank);

        //increments hours by 1
        hours = hours + 1;
    }
    //if hours drops below 24 it will print this output
    if (hours < 24) {
        printf("Out of water at hour %d when remaining gallons were %f\n", hours, fishTank);
    }
    //if hours is greater then 24 by the time the loop ends it will print this.
    else if (hours >= 24) {
        printf("Get out the BBQ and lets eat fish.\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the equation

```
 fishTank = fishTank - (fishTank * .1) + addWater;
```

If at the beginning `fishTank` is  `> 100`, `(fishTank * .1)` cannot decrease `fishTank` if `addWater` >= 10, because after some iterations `fishTank * 0.1` becomes equal to `addWater`.

I suppose, that your solution is correct, but you should provide an alternative way out of the loop. For example, change the condition for `while` as

```
  while (hours <= 24 && fishTank >= 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

The tank looses 10% of it's current volume every hour, which if it has 100 units is 10 units. It gains whatever the user enters. If this number is greater than 10, every time it could drop below 100 it's gaining enough to go above 100 again. Even if it gets back to exactly 100, adding 10 or more is enough to keep it there – so it loops forever

Your while statement needs to be:

```
while (fishTank >= 100 && hours < 24) {
```